# Prevent rotation of markers on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I am using google map and added several custom markers.

My problem is when i rotate my map using fingers, my markers are also rotated.

Can any one give me suggestion, how can i prevent rotation for markers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer my self and posting answer so it can help to others.

Just set marker's flat property to false will prevent rotation of marker.

```html
  MY_MARKER = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .flat(false)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `public MarkerOptions rotation (float rotation)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions.html#rotation(float)

This method returns the object for which the method was called, with the new rotation set.

So when you rotate, you can keep calling this function to rotate the marker back

Comment: Can you tell me how can i use rotation() method. I have list of markers and i have maintain each marker object?